# Generating new random variable with for loop

Tags: r, variables, for-loop, sum

A TA wants me to create a new random variable `Y_n=sum(X_i)`, where X_i are n binomial random variables, with N = 4 and p = 1/3. This wasn't too bad; I just use the following for loop: `for(i in 1:100){yn[i] <- c(sum(rbinom(i, 4, (1/3))))}`. However, he then wants me to recreate Y_n for every tenth number from 1 to 10,000 (i.e., 10, 20, 30,...,9990,10000). I tried to use this code: `yseq <- seq(10, 10000, by=10)
for(i in yseq){
    Y2[i] <- c(sum(rbinom(i,4,(1/3))))}`. It sorta works, but not really. It returns a list (I checked its class) with seemingly correct values, but a bunch of NAs. This has created two problems for me: 1) R won't let me reclass the list as a vector, and 2) R tells me that the list is length 1, which is a bunch of rubbish.

Can some *please* tell me where I am going wrong? I've said it before: programming is not my forte, but I am always doing my best to learn!

Thanks!

Comment: You are getting NA's as the Y2 vector is only defined every tenth value; ie at Y2[10], Y2[20] etc. So NA's are created for Y2[1:9] and so on. So one way is to define as 'Y2[i/10] <-' in your loop or use sapply(yseq , function(ii)  sum(rbinom(ii,4,(1/3)))). Also a list was not produced when i used your code.

Comment: Terrific, thanks so much for your help. Follow-up question: using the for loop in this way, am I generating a fresh set of random variables to sum, each time the loop iterates? My TA specifically asked that we not "generate a single vector of size 10000 for X and calculate the Y_n from this single vector."

Comment: Yes, the first iteration produces rbinom(10,4,0.33) (so length 10), the next rbinom(20,4,0.33) (length 20) and so on - so they are different generations.

Comment: Terrific. Thanks a million.